# Using free() on pointers of two dimensional array with multiple malloc()?

Tags: c, function, pointers, multidimensional-array, free

I have a function that allocates a two dimensional array within a function returning a pointer to the array. Creating the array requires an array of pointers each of which contains the address of a row of the two dimensional array.

How do I correctly free these two `malloc()` calls outside of this function once I am done with this array?

```
int** allocateMatrix(int rows, int cols)
{
    int* arr = malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(int));
    int** matrix = malloc(rows*sizeof(int*));
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<rows; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = &(arr[i*cols]);
    }
    return matrix;
 }
```

The function is used like this:

```
int** 2d_arr = allocateMatrix(row,cols);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only pass to `free` what was received from `malloc`.  So the number of calls to `free` must  be the same as the number of calls to `malloc`.

The first row of `2d_arr`, i.e. `2d_arr[0]`, contains `&arr[0*cols]` == `&arr[0]` == `arr`.  So you want to free that and `matrix` itself:

```
free(2d_arr[0]);
free(2d_arr);
```

Comment: Is it ok when i do: free(2d_arr[0]); outside the func

Comment: @TimWeissenfels Yes, since `2d_arr` contains the same value as `matrix`, the effect is the same.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! but what I 
do not understand is why I only have to free() the first index from matrix :)

Comment: @TimWeissenfels You can only pass to `free` what was passed to `malloc`.  So two of each.

Comment: @TimWeissenfels Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
void freeMatrix( int **matrix )
{
    free( matrix[ 0 ] );
    free( matrix );
}
```

Because, for `i == 0`, this code

```
matrix[i] = &(arr[i*cols]);
```

sets `matrix[ 0 ]` to the address of `arr[0]`, which is the same value returned from the first `malloc` call:

```
int* arr = malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(int));
```

It's clearer if you write matrix allocation like

```
int** allocateMatrix(int rows, int cols)
{
    int** matrix = malloc(rows*sizeof(int*));
    matrix[ 0 ] = malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(int));

    int i;
    for(i=1; i<rows; i++)
    {
            matrix[i] = &(arr[i*cols]);
    }
    return matrix;
 }
```

Note the change in `malloc()` order, the direct assignment to `matrix[ 0 ]`, and the change in loop index to start at `1`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use a single `malloc()` to allocate the entire memory area so as to make it easier to manage as a single pointer.

I believe the following modified version of your function should work.

```
int** allocateMatrix(int rows, int cols)
{
    size_t  sMemSize = rows*sizeof(int*) + rows*cols*sizeof(int);
    int** matrix = malloc(sMemSize);
    int* arr = (int *) (matrix + rows);
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<rows; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = &(arr[i*cols]);
    }
    return matrix;
 }
```

Then you can just do `free(2d_arr);` where `int** 2d_arr = allocateMatrix (nRows, nCols);`.